# asp.net mvc3 jquery custom listbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am wondering is it possible to have a list box that has custom "view" for each of the items.

i.e. I have `<a>` add items to a collection but I have want the list item to appear as such:

ListBoxItem = [ Some Label, Some ComboxBox, Some CheckBox]

Note: I don't want to use a grid.

I can do this easily in WPF application as DataTemplate.

Hopefully that give you guys enough info.

Comment: Is it just that you want a scrolling area?

Comment: No... something that will allow me put complex listbox items in a listbox

Comment: How does a listbox item that is a checkbox or combobox represent data? Can then listbox item be selected AND the combobox value be chosen?

Comment: Negative..only the combobox can be chosen.. the listbox is more like placeholder. So kinda like ItemsControl is WPF, but this one is for asp.net

Comment: If you don't get a value out of the listbox (which is the purpose of the SELECT element) I kind of fail to understand how its different than just a scrolling DIV element.  But you could always use something like the jquery UI selectable component if you really need a selectable list with interactable items.

Comment: actually... you are right. I should just use a div element. I will do that. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was new to this. I didn't realize we can just use div to create a lot of things I was looking for.